# Custom button to delete some tasks

Tags: apex, soql, javascript

I'm trying to create a custom button which deletes a list of Tasks, depending on certain criteria.

Here's my custom button code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}

var Acc = new sforce.SObject("Account");
Acc.Id = "{!Account.Id}";
Acc.Name = "{!Account.Name}";
Acc.Type = "{!Account.Type}";

var TaskList = sforce.apex.execute("AccountManagementTaskController","deleteObsoleteTasks",Acc);

sforce.connection.delete(TaskList);
```

and the method it's calling:

```
WebService static List<Task> deleteObsoleteTasks (Account Acc ) { 

    List<Task> obsoleteTasks = [
        SELECT Id, Type, Status, WhatId
        FROM Task
        WHERE WhatId = Acc.Id
        AND Type = 'Account Managment'
        AND Status = 'Not Applicable'
    ];

    return obsoleteTasks;
}
```

It doesn't seem to like this part of the SOQL query:

> WHERE WhatId = Acc.Id

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's not technically part of the problem, but your `deleteObsoleteTasks` method has a very misleading name - `getObsoleteTasksForDeletion` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to delete the tasks in the apex class as suggested - seems to be working perfectly now.

apex class:

```
WebService static String deleteObsoleteTasks (Account Acc,  String command) { 

    List<Task> obsoleteTasks = [
        SELECT Id, Type, Status, WhatId
        FROM Task
        WHERE WhatId = :Acc.Id
        AND Type = 'Account Management'
        AND Status = 'Not Applicable'
    ];


    if( obsoleteTasks.size() == 0 ) {
        command = 'There are no relevant tasks related to this account so no action will be taken.';
        delete obsoleteTasks;
    } else if (obsoleteTasks.size() ==1 ) {
        command = '1 relevent task will now be deleted.\n\nThe page will refresh in 5 seconds.';
        delete obsoleteTasks;
    } else if (obsoleteTasks.size() > 1 ) { 
        command = '';
        command += obsoleteTasks.size();
        command += ' relevant tasks will now be deleted.\n\nThe page will refresh in 5 seconds.';
        delete obsoleteTasks;
    }
    return command;                 
}
```

and the JS button:

```
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}

var Acc = new sforce.SObject("Account");
Acc.Id = "{!Account.Id}";
Acc.Name = "{!Account.Name}";
Acc.Type = "{!Account.Type}";

function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}

// var TaskList = sforce.apex.execute("AccountManagementTaskController","deleteObsoleteTasks", {"Acc": Acc});

var r=confirm("This will remove all 'Not Applicable' Account Management tasks from the Activity History list and they will be permanently deleted - this action cannot be undone.");
if (r==true) {

    command = sforce.apex.execute("AccountManagementTaskController","deleteObsoleteTasks", {"Acc": Acc});
    alert(command);
    timedRefresh(5000);

} else {

    command = 'No action taken';
    alert(command);

}
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 6):

Add a colon (:) in front of Acc.Id to make the SOQL statement substitute in the variable

```
List<Task> obsoleteTasks = [
        SELECT Id, Type, Status, WhatId
        FROM Task
        WHERE WhatId = :Acc.Id
        AND Type = 'Account Managment'
        AND Status = 'Not Applicable'
    ];
```

There is also an error in the JS, When calling `sforce.apex.execute` the 3rd parameter needs to be a json object:

```
var TaskList = sforce.apex.execute("AccountManagementTaskController","deleteObsoleteTasks", {"Acc": Acc});
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, that worked and successfully deployed the code. However now when I click the custom button I get the following error "A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:

{faultcode:'soapenv:Client', faultstring:'The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.', }"

Comment: I will update my answer now but the 3rd parameter of sforce.apex.execute needs to be a json object :)

Comment: Thanks again Jon, almost there I think but now it doesn't like the delete function: 'sforce.connection.delete is not a function'. Any ideas?

Comment: The call is actually `deleteIds`, since `delete` is a JavaScript keyword. You might also have to massage your list a little, since `deleteIds` takes an array of record IDs, and you're passing it a list of Task objects.

Comment: Might it be worth you doing the delete within the Apex webservice to save passing the Ids back to JS?